# redux/react mapping state to props with large amounts of data queuing state updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, socket.io, react-redux

Using sockets to listen to the server; the Redux store continually updates with thousands of records of data. The updating of the store only takes a couple of seconds with thousands of objects getting dispatched through actions. However, using the redux connect function to map state to my component with mapStateToProps seems to queue up the changes to the state and updates the state of the component at around 7-10 records per second. This means the React Component takes a really long time to render. Are there any solutions to speed this up? Also, the exact amount of data will always be changing and there is no fixed amount.

Here is my component:

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.connectToSocket();
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, width, people, vehicles, incidents, locations } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
         Hello
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TestComponent.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);
    return {
      people: state.live.people,
      vehicles: state.live.vehicles,
      incidents: state.live.incidents,
      locations: state.live.locations
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  connectToSocket: connectToSocket
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps(TestComponent));
```

The action that initialises the socket is executed in the componentDidMount() function. I can then see the state being printed in the console, however, it prints every update with around 7-10 new records a second. With over 5000 updates to the store occurring in a very short time span, mapping the redux store to the props of the component takes a much longer time and it takes over 5 minutes to render the component.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you going to use all the data fetched in this component at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, all the data is required for the component and additional updates to the store will also be required

Comment: So all fetched data are going to be rendered at the same time ? Well I don't think this is efficient in both user experience and performance. It would be better if you do a pagination somehow. In that case for example the first 100 records will be rendered, the rest will be fetched and stored in the state but your component will not render since you will be passing only a portion of the data to the component in mapStateToProps

Comment: The component will require all the data to be rendered live on a map so it is all required.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the answers here involve some form of batching:

- You could batch up the data coming from the socket, so that instead of dispatching N actions with 1 value apiece, you maybe dispatch 5 actions with N/5 values each, or something along that line.
- You can use one of the various batching middleware or store enhancers to cut down on the number of Redux subscription notifications.

See the [Redux FAQ entry on reducing the number of store update events](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#how-can-i-reduce-the-number-of-store-update-events) for further ideas and links.